# How can i put where clause in symfony repository query in controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Initially I am using this

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('AcmePanduBundle:Checklist')->findAll();
```

Now I want that if `pid` variable is present then it should filter the query with something

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('AcmePanduBundle:Checklist')->findAll('where pid=1')
```

and if its not present then findAll should work.

Can I do that in controller or do I have to make a custom function in repository class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do that in the controller:

```
$entities = (isset($pid))
    ? $em->getRepository('AcmePanduBundle:Checklist')->findByPid($pid)
    : $em->getRepository('AcmePanduBundle:Checklist')->findAll();
```

However, this is the type of thing that custom repositories were made for. If you plan on replicating this logic in more than one place, I'd definitely create one.

It would look something like:

```
// src/Acme/PanduBundle/Repository/ChecklistRepository.php
namespace Acme\PanduBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ChecklistRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllWithOptionalPid($pid = null)
    {
        if($pid)
            return $this->findByPid($pid);
        return $this->findAll();
    }
}
```

...and don't forget to reference this repository in your Doctrine configuration. Don't know what method you're using for configuration (xml, yml, annotations), but here's the documentation for that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Once that's done, any controller calling `$em->getRepository('AcmePanduBundle:Checklist')->findAllWithOptionalPid($pid);` will work as you expect it to, with or without the $pid variable.

Comment: I have to implement the same thing acroos 15 entities. Is it possible that i can pass the enitity in the parameter so that i can use one function for all entities in all controller

Comment: I would create an abstract class between the EntityRepository and the CheckListRepository. Something like: ChecklistRepository extends EntityWithPidRepository, which extends EntityRepository. Put your findAllWithOptionalPid() method into that abstract class, and then any repository class extending it will have access to that method. This way, you'll only have to write/maintain the code in one place, but you have access to it from all 15 custom repository classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [findBy or dynamic methods](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database) like "findByPid"

```php
$repository = $em->getRepository('AcmePanduBundle:Checklist');
if ($pid) {
    $entities = $repository->findBy(array('pid' => $pid));
    // or: $entities = $repository->findByPid($pid);
} else {
    $entities = $repository->findAll();
}
```